Negotiate Authentication validating user. Result: {result=BH, notes={message: received type 1 NTLM token
I have a Kerberos environment where my proxy expects Kerberos authentication. This environment has three hosts, a Windows client (joined to AD), a linux host running the proxy (joined to AD) and the AD server. From the Windows client, all internet access are routed through the proxy (after successful proxy authentication using Kerberos).
The set up was working fine, until I changed the AD admin user password (from AD server). After this, I am getting "Negotiate Authentication validating user. Result: {result=BH, notes={message: received type 1 NTLM token"
Looking at the network packet on client using Wireshark , I do get "Proxy-Authenticate: Negotiate" from the proxy, but my browser is sending this:
Proxy-Authorization: Negotiate T<token>

NTLM Secure Service Provider

NTLMSSP identifier: NTLMSSP

NTLM Message Type: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE (0x00000001)

Negotiate Flags: 0xe2088297, Negotiate 56, Negotiate Key Exchange, Negotiate 128, Negotiate Version, Negotiate Extended Session Security, Negotiate Always Sign, Negotiate NTLM key, Negotiate Lan Manager Key, Negotiate Sign, Request Target

Calling workstation domain: NULL
Calling workstation name: NULL

and I get a popup asking for userid and password, which is happening because the client is somehow trying to NTLM instead of Negotiate ?
How can I correct this to use Kerberos (Negotiate) authentication ? I am using FQDN and not the IP for proxy host in proxy settings.
Also note that if I create a new AD user and sign-in using that user, it correctly uses Kerbero auth (without any popup for userid/passwd). Any help appreciated.

Did the client log out from Windows after the password change? What kind of Kerberos messages do you see between the client system and the KDC (e.g. in Wireshark)?

Thanks for your reply @user1686. Yes, I did logout and reboot as well.

Thanks for your reply @user1686. Yes, I did logout and reboot as well. I do not see any Kerberos message in Wireshark. I appears for the first 407 (authentication required) response from proxy, the client is constructing NTML headers and sending the response.  On the Active Directory server  Server Manager--> Local Server --> Events, I see this event. "Microsoft Windows Server has detected that NTLM authentication is presently being used between clients and this server. This event occurs once per boot of the server on the first time a client uses NTLM with this server"

That's odd; Does the user still have access to other resources via Kerberos – does klist (specifically C:\Windows\system32\klist) show other tickets such as those for LDAP or CIFS? There ought to be some right after a logon, or at least when a SMB share is accessed.

klist is slightly different for the user who NTLM is being used (the user whose password was changed) and the new user for whom Kerberos auth is being used.

For the user where ntlm  is being used, the klist has Server: krbtgt/ @  and Server: ldap/@.
For the user where kerberos is being used, apart from above tickets, it also has
Server: HTTP/@
I don't know if missing HTTP/proxy ticket is causing the issue or it is missing because of the same reason Kerberos auth is not being used.
